# EF 6.1.3 automatic migrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I created an initial migration into my database when I executed a database operation via code first.

All the tables got created successfully.

I have successfully enabled automatic migrations.

I've added a couple of columns to a model.

When I run the "Update-Database –Verbose", I get an error message (which I understand, but don't now why it's coming out) of "**There is already an object named 'Categories' in the database.**"

**The Categories table along with all the rest of the tables got created on the initial migration** (as explained above).

I made a change (adding the two other columns) to another model (Customer).

I would think, that the Code First migration would simply look at the entire DBSet model, determine what changed, then simply apply the necessary SQL. Instead, it's trying to create the Categories table again which already exists.

**Can someone please explain to me how I can simply update the DB without this happening? What am I doing wrong or what do I need to do in order to get it to work....**

### EDIT

Successful creation of EF code-first Migrations setup:

- Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations

  - Add-Migration Initial (Creates _Initial.cs file).
  - Comment out code in _Initial.cs file within Migrations folder for 
    code that you don't want to execute AFTER initial DB run to create tables.
  - Set Configuration.cs file to Public access
  - Add following code in Global.asax file

```
    Database.SetInitializer(new 
        MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion());
```

- Update-Database - Verbose (for any DB changes)

  - Set "AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;" in Configuration.cs 
    file within Migrations folder. (for any DB changes)

Comment: Right, if you did an initial migration subsequent migrations should not ask to create those. You can comment them out in the Up()/Down() and see if it sticks with the next migration. http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/using-ef-4-3-code-first-migrations-with-an-existing-database/

Comment: Ok, I see where you're going with this after reading the article. What I did was run a database operation which created all the tables in my DB. The record "201503232214438_InitialCreate" is inside my newly create DB. There is no "201503232214438_InitialCreate.cs" file in my solution project. This is where I would need to comment out the "Up|Down" methods. How do I get this file created into my solution? I just have the Configuration.cs file in my Migrations folder for the project. Those methods are not included in there as well.

Comment: The "InitialCreate.cs" file was supposed to be created inside the same migrations folder when I enabled automatic migrations, but only the "Configuration.cs" file was created... How can I get the "InitialCreate.cs" file inside that folder?

Comment: When I do add-migration 'Initial' it creates the yyyymmddhhmm_Initial.cs class in my migration folder. When I do the update-database it applies it and adds a record to the table. Do you have more than 1 context? You can set the migration folder and namespace in the Configuration constructor, but I didn't need to do that. MigrationsDirectory = @"Data\Migrations";

Comment: I was able to successfully create it doing the following steps in my EDIT.